# Unexpected behaviour of 'attempts' option in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, resolv.conf

I'd like Linux to make only one request to DNS server, wait for 5 sec timeout and then abort the lookup if no answer.

To do this I set the following options in `/etc/resolv.conf` assuming that `attempts` element in `options` means the exact number of DNS requests:

```
nameserver 'DNS Server IP address'
domain     'Domain Name'
options     attempts:1 timeout:5
```

But the system behaves unexpectedly. In fact for these settings I observe:

```
DNS request
Wait for a 5 sec timeout
DNS request repeat
Wait for a 5 sec timeout
```

If I set attempts:2, there will be 4 requests.

1. Do I correctly understand that '1 attempt' in fact means 'make a request and then re-request after timeout'?
2. Is there a way to change this behaviour so the system would send only one DNS request in scope of 1 attempt?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation looks correct to me.

Did you check what these two queries are? Maybe the first one is for `AAAA` record and second one is for `A` record, which is the normal behavior.
If so, try adding `inet6:off` in `options`
Also, probably trivial, but verify the number of `nameserver` items you have. The timeout is for each of them sequentially.

Comment: `inet6:off` terrible advice

Comment: Yes, this is only to debug the reason for the two queries.

Comment: Or run tcpdump?

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the answers. By 'DNS request' I mean both A and AAAA type of queries. So in fact I observe in traces 'A request, AAA reguest, timeout, A request, AAAA request, timeout'.  So both types of queries are duplicated.